# Angular loading data from server json

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

Can someone tell me whats the best solution to use jsonObjects in ng repeat?
My code is as follows:

My PHP response is this:

```
die(json_encode(array('sts'=>'success', 'title'=>'*****', 'msg'=>'*******', 'data'=>$result)));
```

My angular.js the service is like this:

```
LeadApp.service('LeadsService', function ($http) {
  var AllLeads = {
    async: function() {
        var promise = $http({
            url: '../app/ServerData.php',
            method: "POST",
            params: { req_id: 'leads' }
        }).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
      });
      return promise;
    }
  };
  return AllLeads;
});
```

Then in my controller i call the service and set a lead var to use in my view with ng repeat: My Data is being loaded i assured already. I attached a pic of the console log from below. But somehow the ng repeat just wont work like expected... What am i doing wrong? There is no error!

```
    ....
        LeadsService.async().then(function (d) {
                this.leads = d.data;
                console.log(this.leads);
       this.list_all = this.leads;
```

Here is the main ng repeat part in the view (custom ng repeat with "dir-paginate"):
...

```
<div class="widget-content leads_list" ng-controller="leadsController as leads">
<tr dir-paginate="lead in leads.list_all | orderBy:sortKey:reverse | filter:search | itemsPerPage:15" pagination-id="leads.list_all">
    <td scope="row">{{lead.id}}</td>
```

...

Comment: Where is your ng-repeat code? Can you post the ng-repeat part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `this` context outside `then` method.

Since you are using `ng-controller="leadsController as leads"`, it would be wise to bind to the variable `leads`.

```
var leads = this;
LeadsService.async().then(function (d) {
        leads.list_all = d.data;
        console.log(leads.list_all);
});
```

The `this` context inside the `then` method is not the same as the `this` context outside the `then` method. Also binding to the same name that you use in your template helps to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not the controller in that callback function context. So you need to assign `this` to a variable in the controller.

```
 var ctrl = this;

 LeadsService.async().then(function (d) {
        ctrl.leads = d.data;
        console.log(ctrl.leads);
```